# mariadb earlier versions

Tags: 22.04, mysql, mariadb, zabbix

So I'm using zabbix 6 which does not actually support mariadb above 10.08

I manage to install mariadb 10.08 but today I see a log message that says:

the repository ( meaning mariadb 10.08) no longer has a release file.

```
my question is this:
are mariadb earlier versions won't work anymore!?
```

Comment: Which repository is being reported as having the error? If you installed MariaDB on an earlier version of Ubuntu, then upgraded Ubuntu, I can see this as a possible issue. You may just need to change a definition in a configuration file if you’re using an alternative source for MariaDB 

Comment: I'm running the latest version of ubuntu.. except for the mariadb 10.10 repository, all repositories under the mariadb 10.10 version are having the error!

Comment: one of the repositories are https://dlm.mariadb/repo/mariadb-server/10.08/repo/ubuntu/ jammy